# FileReader.readAsBinaryString() is not support IE 10, 11

Tags: javascript, filereader

The below code works in chrome browser.

```
$('#file').change(function(e) {
    var fileReader = new FileReader(),
        file = e.target.files[0];

        if (typeof fileReader.readAsBinaryString == "function") {
            // section #1
            var binaryString, base64;

            fileReader.onload = function(readerEvt) {
                binaryString = readerEvt.target.result;
                base64 = 'data:'+type+';base64,'+btoa(binaryString);
                socket.emit('image', { image: base64, size: file.size, filename: file.name });
            }

            fileReader.readAsBinaryString(file);
        }else{

            // section #2 in IE 10, 11...
            var binary = "", bytes = e.target.result, length = bytes.length;

            for (var i=0; i<length; i++) {
                binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
            }

            // How can I control 'binary' variable for IE 10, 11

        }
});
```

I want to make it work the same as in Google Chrome.

Please implementing the source code into section #2.

Comment: Looks supported in IE10. See MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh772310(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: "Please implement the source code into section #2" Sorry, not how it works.

Comment: Section 2 must be the answer field

Comment: @Drakes How can I create the same result as section #1? (image file encode to base64). section #2 don't work it well. can't get e.target.result and 'length=bytes.length';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All though the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn792847(v=vs.85).aspx) says that the `readAsBinaryString` function is defined, but it still gives `Can't be resolved` and `function definition not found` errors.

You can try this code. It has worked for me. Please refer my comments for the help.

I have tested the code in **IE 11** and **Chrome**.

**Html Code**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.8.0/jszip.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.8.0/xlsx.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="file" id="files" onchange="handleFileSelect(event)"/>
    <output id="list"></output>
</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript Code**

```
//readAsBinaryString function is not defined in IE
//Adding the definition to the function prototype
if (!FileReader.prototype.readAsBinaryString) {
    console.log('readAsBinaryString definition not found');

    FileReader.prototype.readAsBinaryString = function (fileData) {
        var binary = '';
        var pk = this;
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            var bytes = new Uint8Array(reader.result);
            var length = bytes.byteLength;

            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                var a = bytes[i];

                var b = String.fromCharCode(a)
                binary += b;
            }

            pk.content = binary;
            $(pk).trigger('onload');
        }

        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileData);
    }
}

function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    console.log(evt);

    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e){
        if (reader.result)
            reader.content = reader.result;

        //In IE browser event object is null
        var data = e ? e.target.result : reader.content;
        var baseEncoded = btoa(data);
        var wb = XLSX.read(baseEncoded, {type: 'base64'});

        processWorkbook(wb);
    };

    reader.onerror = function(ex){
        console.log(ex);
    };

    //I'm reading the first file
    //You can modify it as per your need
    console.log(evt.target.files[0]);

    reader.readAsBinaryString(evt.target.files[0]);
}

function processWorkbook(workbook) {

    console.log(workbook.Sheets['sheet_name']['excel_cell_name_to_be_accessed'].v);

    //For example
    console.log(workbook.Sheets['sheet1']['C2'].v);

    //you can iterate through all the sheets
    for(var i = 0; i < workbook.SheetNames.length; i++) {
        workbook.SheetNames[i]['cell_name_to_be_accessed'] //rest of the processing
    }

    //You can now work with the workbook as per your requirements
}
```